# VBA auto-email with multiple reciepients

Tags: vba, email, ms-access-2010

I am having a hard time getting my `.To = emails` to recognize multiple email addresses in this code.
I am trying to use the `SELECT` function to grab a list of email addresses `WHERE Active` (a Yes/No checkbox) is true. Then trying to insert this list into the `.To = <list of multiple email addresses>`. I want to avoid using Outlook with this automated email, and obtaining a list of email addresses it will be sent to stored in a table for ease of management so that no one needs to go into the code to adjust the addresses. Am I going about this the wrong way?

```
<code above here>

Dim dbs As Database, emails As Recordset

Set dbs = CurrentDb

Set emails = dbs.OpenRecordset "SELECT EmailAddy FROM EmailTbl WHERE Active = -1;")

emails.MoveLast

With iMsg
    .Configuration = iCfg
    .To = emails
    .CC = ""

<code below here>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `iMsg.To` probably accepts a delimited string of email addresses, just like the [`DoCmd.SendObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197046.aspx) command. Below is an example of how you could pull together such a string.

```
' Update this constant to a comma, pipe, etc. as needed
Const EMAIL_DELIMITER As String = ";"
' Stores the delimited list of emails
Dim emailList As String
With CurrentDb
    With .OpenRecordset "SELECT EmailAddy FROM EmailTbl WHERE Active = -1;")
        Do While Not .EOF
            ' This IsNull check is not necessary if EmailAddy is never null
            If Not IsNull(!EmailAddy) Then 
                emailList = emailList & !EmailAddy & EMAIL_DELIMITER 
            End If
            .MoveNext
        Loop
        .Close
    End With
End With    
' Lob off the trailing delimiter
If Len(emailList) Then emailList = Left(emailList, Len(emailList) - Len(EMAIL_DELIMITER))
```